# Compare std::error_code with integers

Tags: c++, error-code

My setup: macOS with Xcode/clang

From [examples of std::error_code](https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/examples/error_code-example/), it seems that it's compatible with enum, e.g., you can assign an enum to it, 
but when comparing it with an integer like this:

```
if (my_error_code == 0)
```

I got

```
Invalid operands to binary expression ('const std::error_code' and 'int')
```

How should I test an error_code against a known integer such as `errno`s?

Answer (score 3):

`std::error_code` can't be compared with an `int` directly; you might want [`std::error_code::value`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/error_code/value) to get the value of the error_code. (And you might also need the help of [`category`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/error_code/category).)

> Returns the platform dependent error value.

Answer (score 2):

> How should I test an error_code against a known integer such as errnos?

You should compare against the [`std::errc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/errc) enum members that correspond to `errno` integers.

If for whatever reason you can't / don't want to do that, then compare against a new `error_code` constructed from the appropriate category and `value`.